# Getting different scenarios from minus table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this two tables:

Table A

```
ID  TYPE    SDATE   EDATE   RATING

1   M   1/1/2010    1/1/2011    A
1   M   1/3/2010    1/4/2011    B
2   A   7/2/2010    1/31/2015   C
3   M   3/1/2011    1/20/2012   B
4   A   3/1/2011    1/20/2012   B
5   M   3/1/2009    3/1/2009    F
6   M   12/31/2006  12/31/9999  A
7   A   1/1/2006    12/31/9999  B
```

Table B

```
ID  TYPE    SDATE   EDATE   RATING

1   M   1/1/2010    1/1/2011    A
2   A   7/2/2010    1/31/2015   C
2   A   9/2/2010    1/31/2015   C
3   M   3/1/2011    1/20/2012   B
4   A   3/1/2011    1/20/2012   C
6   M   12/31/2006  12/31/2015  A
7   A   2/1/2006    12/31/9999  B
8   M   1/2/2010    1/2/2012
```

When I perform a table A minus table B, it gets me the next result:

```
ID  TYPE    SDATE   EDATE   RATING

1   M   1/3/2010    1/4/2011    B
4   A   3/1/2011    1/20/2012   B
5   M   3/1/2009    3/1/2009    F
6   M   12/31/2006  12/31/9999  A
7   A   1/1/2006    12/31/9999  B
```

I have already identified the case where A.id is not in B.id, but how do I check when it is different in some other column?

I'm not allowed to create anything on the schema, so I have to do it through queries.

So far, this is what I have, but it gives me data that is not correct.

```
    with aminusb as
    (
        select
            *
        from A
        minus
        select
            *
        from B
    )
    select
        diff.*
    from
        aminusb diff
        ,B
    where
        diff.id = B.id
        and
            diff.start_date = B.start_date
        and
            diff.end_date = B.end_date
        and
            diff.rating <> B.rating
```

Do you know how could I get the different scenarios?

- When everything is equal but, rating.
- When everything is equal but, end date.
- When nothing is equal but, it has the same id.

I need to get a list of the records that fulfill every scenario so people can check it on detail.

Thanks.

Comment: You might try [unpivoting](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php) A-B and B-A, join the results on ID and ColumnName and filter out ones having the same Value. After that you will have a list of differences by columns.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Hi, I tried with something like this, but it seems that it doesn't work for oracle 10g. `with aminusb as     (
SELECT   * FROM A
MINUS
SELECT   * FROM B
)
      select diff
      from
      aminusb diff,B
      where
      diff.id = B.id
      and             diff.start_date = B.start_date
      and             diff.end_date = B.end_date
      and             diff.rating <> B.rating
unpivot (
    rating_cd for as in (
        SELECT   DISTINCT (id)
        FROM   A
        )
)`

Comment: Which version of Oracle is that?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Oracle 10g

Comment: Oh well, we are out of luck. Oracle 11g introduced unpivoting, as it is written in link above: `This article shows how to use the new PIVOT and UNPIVOT operators in 11g`. You might do it by hand in a series of union alls, one for each column, but this would be cumbersome and ugly. Perhaps you might hilight differences in presentation level of application?

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Well, at least we tried. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give uncommon rows:

```
 Select startdate, enddate, rating 
   from TableA 
Intersect 
 Select startdate, enddate, rating 
   from TableB
```

To Show All records:

```
 Select TableA.startdate, TableA.enddate, TableA.rating
  from TableA 
UNION 
 Select startdate, enddate, rating 
 from TableB
```

Case 1:

```
 Select TableA.*, TableB.* 
   from tableA,TableB 
  Where TableA.StartDate = tableB.StartDate  
    And tableA.Enddate=TableB.Enddate 
    And TableA.Rating <>TableB.Rating
```

And TableA.Rating = TableB.Rating

Case 2:

```
 Select TableA.*, TableB.*
   from tableA,TableB 
  Where TableA.StartDate = tableB.StartDate 
    And tableA.Enddate<>TableB.Enddate
    And TableA.Rating = TableB.Rating
```

Case 3:

```
 Select TableA.*, TableB.* 
   from tableA,TableB 
  Where TableA.StartDate <> tableB.StartDate 
    And tableA.Enddate<>TableB.Enddate 
    And TableA.Rating <>TableB.Rating
    And TableA.ID =TableB.ID
```

Comment: @Jeffrey-Kemp Hi, I tried your proposed solution but I realized that there are duplicated values and the id is not unique. When I tried the table with the minus, I got 1400 differences, with the code you gave me it threw more than 5000. Sorry.

Comment: @StrayChild01, I just edited the answer for clarity. This is Naval's solution.

Comment: @Naval Hi Naval, I tried your solution and I couldn't get what I need. Please see my first comment to it.

Comment: @StrayChild01 which  of the cases did u try ?

Comment: @Naval Hi Naval, sorry for the late answer. The trouble was that one of the tables was in fact a view, and everytime that I ran it, it gave me different results. I had to track down the whole thing, but the queries were correct. Thanks.